# The quick fix feature for importing classes from other packages in Scala doesn't work in vscode and metals

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scala-metals

I used the quick fix that provided by vscode to automatically import the package, but it doesn't work. how can i solve it?
[image]

And this is my metals doctor in this project.
[image]

Maybe metals doesn't support the quick fix feature?

I installed an old version of vscode. Metals also installed an older version. Also, I changed JDK 11 and 17 versions. I also installed only metals extension to avoid conflicts with other vscode extensions.

If I click quick fix, it should expect to be entered at the top of the file like "import seed.model.Person"

Comment: You may want to also ask in the official **Discord** channel: https://discord.com/channels/632642981228314653/632652693013528589

Comment: NVM, As a workaround, I decided to develop using WSL. Using WSL it works fine. peace!

Comment: If, like me, you want to migrate your dev env to WSL, check out this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode